# Which method should I use instead of setLatestInfo?

Tags: android, methods, notifications

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to show some status bar notification on the user.I found out that API23+ does not support the method setLatestInfo, so my compiler finds it as an error. What other method should I use instead of this to turn on notifications?

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;
import static android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;


public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    Switch simpleswitch1;
    Switch simpleswitch2;
    private Notification notification;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


        simpleswitch1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch1);
        simpleswitch2 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleswitch2);
        simpleswitch1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Notify("Title", "Message");
            }


        });
        simpleswitch2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;




                }});}


    private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification, "New message", System.currentTimeMillis());

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, Settings.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(Settings.this, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setLatestEventInfo` is **deprecated**, was removed in api 23. So if your SDK version is set to api 23+ you'll have this issue and you should use **NotificationCompat.Builder** instead.

An example :

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, Settings.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
        .setContentTitle("New message")
        .setContentText("My notification")
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build();

    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notificationManager.notify(11 /*An identifier for this notification unique within your application.*/, notification);

}
```

I suggest to read the official documentation about notification [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java).